# How to change a EhCache members expiry time programmatically

Tags: java, ehcache

I would like to change the expiry or set the expiry time of a member of an EhCache via Java code.

I know when the object should expire, but I'm unsure how to achieve this.

I know I can set it for the whole cache, e.g.

```
Cache cache = manager.getCache("sampleCache");
CacheConfiguration config = cache.getCacheConfiguration();
config.setTimeToIdleSeconds(60);
config.setTimeToLiveSeconds(120);
config.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(10000);
config.setMaxEntriesLocalDisk(1000000);
```

Can someone suggest how I do this for a specific member?

Comment: It may help if you could tell what are you trying to achieve. Could you provide a use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ehcache 2.x, you can set expiry time on the `Element` you insert in the cache:

```
Element element = new Element("key1", "value1");
element.setTimeToLive(300);
```

In Ehcache 3.x, you can implement a custom `Expiry` and have it return different `Duration` depending on the `key` and `value`:

```
public interface Expiry<K, V> {
  Duration getExpiryForCreation(K key, V value);
  Duration getExpiryForAccess(K key, ValueSupplier<? extends V> value);
  Duration getExpiryForUpdate(K key, ValueSupplier<? extends V> oldValue, V newValue);
}
```

Check the [API documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.0.2/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In Ehcache 3.x, you can implement a custom Expiry at entry level by implementing ExpiryPolicy interface.

```
private static ExpiryPolicy customExpirtyPolicy=new ExpiryPolicy<Integer,CachedObject>(){

    @Override public Duration getExpiryForCreation(Integer key,CachedObject value){return value.getExpiryTime();}

    @Override public Duration getExpiryForAccess(Integer key,Supplier<?extends CachedObject>value){CachedObject cachedObject=value.get();return cachedObject.getExpiryTime();}

    @Override public Duration getExpiryForUpdate(Integer key,Supplier<?extends CachedObject>oldValue,CachedObject newValue){return newValue.getExpiryTime();}

    };
```

Define the cache using custom expiration policy.

```
Cache<Integer, CachedObject> myCache = cacheManager.createCache("myCache",
        CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Integer.class, CachedObject.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100))
                .withExpiry(customExpirtyPolicy).build());
```

Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2022/06/ehcache-programmatically-set-expiry.html).